# Why is my Google App Engine application throwing AccessControlExceptions?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am in panic mode today and would very much appreciate your precious help:

Since three hours now our Java-based Google App Engine application is throwing AccessControlExceptions when it tries to load a FreeMarker template. The code of this application did not change for 11 days. Since approximately 3h however each template loading request throws something like this:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/WEB-INF/freemarker/panel/root.ftl" "read")
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-e5a6df6e4f6e9c58(Request.java)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:382)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:572)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
at java.io.File.isFile(File.java:961)
at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$2.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:165)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.findTemplateSource(FileTemplateLoader.java:161)
at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.acquireTemplateSource(TemplateCache.java:628)
at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.findTemplateSource(TemplateCache.java:618)
at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:316)
at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:205)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:740)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:665)
...
```

As you can see the problem seems to be that the application is not allowed to load this file any more, although it was allowed to load it in the past.

**Did the behaviour of App Engine change when it comes to file reading permissions? Am I missing something?**

Thanksalot for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, see the public issue tracker for more details: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11766